# How to print string methods in Python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following Python code:

```
mystr = 'Hello World'
plist = sorted(list(dir(mystr)))
for p in plist:
    if not p.startswith('__'):
        print(p)
        # print(mystr.p())
```

The `print(p)` statement in the loop will print all string methods from capitalize to zfill.  I actually want to print everything from mystr.capitalize() to mystr.zfill(), but `print(mystr.p())` won't work.  Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Huh?  I cannot discern what you are actually asking.

Comment: Don't stack a `list` call inside `sorted`; `sorted` already implies conversion to `list` (which it then sorts and returns), so all `sorted(list(dir(mystr)))` is doing is 1) Getting a `list` from `dir` 2) Making another temporary `list` copy of said `list` 3) Making another copy, sorting it, and storing it in `plist`. It's already got one extra temporary `list`, you don't need to add more; `sorted(dir(mystr))` is better.

Answer (score 1):

You propably are looking for getattr(). Note, that some methods you want to print require parameters, therefore i added a try.

```
mystr = 'Hello World'
plist = sorted(list(dir(mystr)))
for p in plist:
    if not p.startswith('__'):
        try:
            print(getattr(mystr, p)())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            # print(mystr.p())
```

Comment: Yes, "getattr" function is what I am looking for.

Comment: Not sure why my question is closed and I can't accept your answer as the best one.

Comment: Ah that is unfortunate. Thanks for the feedback though and I am glad I could be of help. If you want you can just upvote it. I get a few points for that. :) Happy Coding!